# Does sci-kit's verbose emit a signal that can be captured and utilized for updating progress bar in PyQt

Tags: scikit-learn, signals, pyqt5, verbose

I am trying to build a GUI for a RandomForest predictor, and I would like to have a progress bar to show the building and predicting process.

Currently I have a gif in QLabel running as long as the process is running, but I am interested to know if it is possible to track the actual progress. I have read about subprocesses tracking the stdout signals, but I haven't figured out the arguments to call any subprocess functions (Popen, run, check_output)

If subprocess is the way to go, what are the arguments I should be using? Or is there any other way to utilize signal emitted by verbose.